# What do i do with Bitcoin? How to start my Bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-cash

I heard a little bit about Bitcoin and people earning money from it. How do i start my Bitcoin. I am very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bitcoin developer portal, here neither you will earn any bitcoin nor anybody will tell how how to earn it and stuff.  If you want to start with bitcoin developement start with [fullnode](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#ubuntu-1610). You will get all required information there